# (Reference request) Is there a better (but also fully technical) source to read how exactly SegWit works other than the official BIP141 document?

Tags: segregated-witness

I'm slowly making my way through https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki and while it seems that with more time I should be able to understand it properly, it's going rather slowly and I feel like it'd be much more efficient to have a source that would explain this somewhat better, perhaps by elaborating more on why it's done exactly this way, with more examples etc.

But also everything else that I've found is just far from technical enough. Any good references you could recommend?

Comment: Do you mean something like https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/ ?

Comment: Not really, it seems to be a rather short, dry description of how to craft segwit-compatible transactions without explaining very much about how segwit works. A good example of what I'm looking for would be something like BIP141, just much longer with more wordy explanations of what's happening.